# Openssh Service not working | Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ssh, openssh, sshd

I installed OpenSSH on windows 10 which is using Kaspersky as my security suite.  When I start the openssh server in powershell on the default port 22 everything works fine. I am able to log into my linux computer and connect to my windows computer.

But I changed the port in the `sshd_config` file to port 12400, I made a firewall rule in kaspersky allowing incoming traffic, but now when I start the openssh server it doesnt work. It throws this error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> start-service sshd
start-service : Failed to start service 'OpenSSH SSH Server (sshd)'.
At line:1 char:1
+ start-service sshd
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-
   Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any log messages (in eventvwr) coming out of sshd itself?

Answer (score -2):

I fixed it by Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Manual With windows 10 built in SSH